# Is there a "run" command for Alt+Tab in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, alt-tab

Is there a "run" command to access the Alt+Tab window switcher in Windows 7?

Ideally, I'd like to re-assign the Alt+Ctrl+Tab persistent app switcher to another, less unwieldy hotkey. I know of AutoHotKey, but it does not work well on my laptop for some reason.

Comment: Would a (non-AutoHotKey) script that does Alt+Ctrl+Tab solve your problem?

Comment: On a personal level, I've solved it by assigning a hotkey to a mouse button using the mouse manufacturer's utility. Please feel free to post a solution here for reference. If it's the best here, I'll accept that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent "run" command. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> is the only way to access this window switcher.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so with the 3D view via

```
rundll32 DwmApi #105
```

but there isn't such a thing for the normal Alt+Tab window that I'm aware of.

Comment: Elaboration: This probably exists as an API call because it was supposed to be triggered by things like mouse drivers or an icon in the task bar (which it was in Windows Vista, as far as I remember). The original Alt+Tab functionality is far older and also controlled by CSRSS which isn't exactly the nicest component to control programmatically from user mode.

Comment: Great answer! I don't know why this wasnt chosen! is there a similar command for CTRL + TAB?